# Why the following function doesn't generate tail recursion with Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, tail-recursion

Under clang the following function generates object code for a tail recursive function:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_prime(T number, T limit, T counter)
{
    return counter >= limit
        ? number % limit != 0
        : number % counter
            ? is_prime(number, number / counter, counter + 2)
            : false;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_prime(T n)
{
    return n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5
        ? true
        : n <= 1 || n % 2 == 0
            ? false
            : is_prime(n, n / 3, T{3});
}
```

but changing one line (letting a boolean result "non-normalized"), it ceases to generate tail recursive object code:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_prime(T number, T limit, T counter)
{
    return counter >= limit
        ? number % limit    // changed here
        : number % counter
            ? is_prime(number, number / counter, counter + 2)
            : false;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_prime(T n)
{
    return n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5
        ? true
        : n <= 1 || n % 2 == 0
            ? false
            : is_prime(n, n / 3, T{3});
}
```

Is it clang failing to optimize it correctly or there's a logical reason for so?

To force runtime evaluation, `x` is a runtime integral prime `≥ 13` (one recursion) or a large enough constexpr prime that would prevent compile-time evaluation because of large recursion depth:

```
is_prime(x);
```

Comment: Removing the != 0 means the result of the ternary statement might not be a bool. The result has to be cast to the right type and thus the recursive call is not the last statement.

Comment: @krsteeve I thought of that before, but it doesn't make sense to me. It's a simple branch, if execution will not get to `number % limit`, it'll be discarded, so, no state is necessary to be saved for the next call, it can be discarded, despite it being with `!= 0` or not, in my view.

Comment: After a bit more digging - If you have exp1 ? exp2 : exp3, to determine the type of the ?: statement the type of exp3 is converted into the type of exp2 (if possible). This means your nice bool result is converted into type T and has to be converted back to bool for return. I'm curious what happens if you reverse your ?: statement

Answer (score 2):

If you have `exp1 ? exp2 : exp3`, to determine the type of the `?:` statement the type of `exp3` is converted into the type of `exp2` (if possible). This means your nice **bool** result is converted into type **T** and has to be converted back to bool for return.

This means that the recursive call is not the last statement. I believe if you reverse the order in the ternary operator you will get the tail recursive result.

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_prime(T number, T limit, T counter)
{
    return counter < limit
        ? (number % counter
            ? is_prime(number, number / counter, counter + 2)
            : false)
        : number % limit;
}
```

Comment: sadly, I just tested it out and it has not worked as you expected. Your sample doesn't produce a tail recursive version (clang version 3.4 trunk 183147). I concur the `?:` casting rule makes sense, since `exp2` can prevent the calling context of being discarded for a tail call of is_prime, since a cast operation is stacked to be applied on such call.